# Indexes with MongoDB Java Driver not improving performance

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, indexing

In my database, i have an index with 100K documents with the following structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f2ce94ef4c3043f12141b8"), "a" : "aaaa", "b" : "bbbb", "c" : "cccc" ...}
```

On Java, after inserting, i call the function:

```
myCollection.createIndex(new Document("a", 1));
```

and in order to query:

```
 FindIterable<Document> iterable = 
DB.getCollection(collection).find(dbobj);
```

After several tests, the performance with or without query is the same.
I'm open to give extra information about my operations.
The explain command gives me:

```
 {
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "db.MyCollection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "a" : /^aaaa.*/i
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "a" : /^aaaa.*/i
                },
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "Modality" : [
                        "[\"\", {})",
                        "[/^aaaa.*/i, /^aaaa.*/i]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: How is your query in `dbobj`?

Comment: Are the speeds the same using the MongoDB console? If it is, could you please run the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) command on your query?

Comment: Please, provide more details. Can you show exact document and exact queries? Can you describe fields cardinality (i.e. how many different values indexed field typically has)? What's data size and how much memory your server has?

Comment: @jarnbjo My query in dbobj is: { "a" : { "$regex" : "^aaaa.*", "$options" : "i" } }

Comment: @CydrickT I add the explain result to the question.

Comment: @Roman I'm working with private data, i can't expose the documents. My Server has 12GB of memory. The fields have only one token on almost all cases.

Comment: The query planner says that it uses the index to query the database (you can see that with the "IXSCAN"), which is good. Could you also show the results of [db.my_collection.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/)? Maybe the size of your database is smaller than the amount of RAM you have, so MongoDB can hold all the documents (and not only the indexed fields) in RAM, which would explain why the query speeds are the same.

Comment: @CydrickT Probably that is the the problem, i have like 12GB RAM on my server, i will try as soon as possible with a 7M docs data set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndréAlves I posted a full answer. Feel free to comment if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments of the question, MongoDB gets slow when all the documents does not fit in memory, and it gets really slow when the indexed fields do not fit in memory. This is because MongoDB has to resort to [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging). This means MongoDB saves some content of the memory on your HDD, and retrieving this is slow. Basically, you are losing the advantage of having indexed fields.

Tactics to avoid that are to:

- Increase the amount of RAM you have on your server
- Use a [sharded configuration](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) containing multiple servers
- Limit data duplication across documents
- Limit the indexed fields

You can observe the amount of memory taken by MongoDB by using the [db.my_collection.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) command on the MongoDB console. This should be the output:

```
{
   "ns" : "guidebook.restaurants",
   "count" : 25359,
   "size" : 10630398,
   "avgObjSize" : 419,
   "storageSize" : 4104192
   "capped" : false,
   "wiredTiger" : {
         "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
         },
         [...]
      "nindexes" : 4,
      "totalIndexSize" : 626688,
      "indexSizes" : {
         "_id_" : 217088,
         "borough_1_cuisine_1" : 139264,
         "cuisine_1" : 131072,
         "borough_1_address.zipcode_1" : 139264
      },
      "ok" : 1
 }
```

`storageSize` shows the amount of memory used to store documents in bytes, and `totalIndexSize` shows the amount of memory used to store indexed values in bytes. You can see which indexed fields takes most of the space in the `indexSizes` sub-document.

Ideally, you want to have more RAM than `storageSize + totalIndexSize`, but you really should have more RAM than `totalIndexSize`.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, you need to use a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) if you want the index to be used for case insensitive queries.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you assume that i need case insensitive queries? I can't use text index because: "A collection can have at most one text index" and i need at least four fields to be indexed.

Comment: @AndréAlves Because the 'i' option you are using means case insensitive: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: Thanks, i will test without the "i" option and if the performance improves i validate your answer